# How do I make my Nokogiri :contains case insensitive?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, case-insensitive, contain

I'm using Ruby 2.4 and Nokogiri.  I have this for finding an element on my page with certain text ...

```
a_elt = doc.at('a:contains("MY TEXT")')
```

How can I make the :contains case insenstiive?  I'm not guaranteed the text will always be upper case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CSS selector rules this should not be possible as far as I know. But XPath 2.0 would able to check for text case insensitive either by transforming the text content with `upper-case()` or using `matches()` with third parameter `'i'` instead of `contains()`, which will match with a case insensitive regular expression. Nokogiri internally transforms CSS selectors into an XPath query, so your example becomes `//a[contains(., "MY TEXT")`. However, Nokogiri's XML features are based on `libxml2` (MRI Ruby) or `javax.xml.xpath` (JRuby) which do not support Xpath 2.0.

If this was supported you could just replace the CSS selector with this XPath query:

```
//a[contains(upper-case(.), "MY TEXT")]
```

But you can just implement the text comparison directly in ruby like this:

```
a_elt = doc.xpath('//a').detect { |node| /MY TEXT/i === node.text }
```

Comment: This results in an error, "NoMethodError: undefined method `text' for #<Array:0x007fee1343a518>"

Comment: Sry, I had mistakenly used `#at`, should be `#xpath` instead. I edited my answer.

Comment: Guess you could do `doc.search("a").detect { ... }`. I would generally recommend to prefer CSS over Xpath because of Xpath's surprising semantics on non-root nodes.

Comment: Whatever you like. Either `#search` as well as `#css` are just calls to `#xpath` internally, so using it directly saves some additional query checking and transformation, but that's just my preference, it won't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very elegant, but it does the job :

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.read("test.html"))

a_elt = doc.at("//a[
                    contains(
                      translate(
                        text(),
                        'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                        'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),
                      'my text')
               ]")

p a_elt.text
#=> "My TeXt Is WeIrD"
```